# Integer overflow takes place even if I type cast to long int (C++)

Tags: c++, casting, integer-overflow

I am trying to understand the phenomenon of overflow and decided to demonstrate the same by executing the piece of code provided below:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a = 100000;
    int b = 100000;
    cout << a * b << endl; 
    long int c = a * 1LL * b;
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is that simply multiplying a and b (as done in line 6) would result in an integer overflow as 10^10 falls outside the range of the integer data type. To overcome this, the product (a*b) is multiplied with the literal '1LL' (as shown in line 7).
The problem is that integer overflow still takes place as the output of the program is:

```
1410065408
1410065408
```

It's possible that I am making a super silly mistake somewhere, but I have spent a sufficient amount of time trying to understand where it's going wrong and am yet to find the reason. Hoping for some help/guidance here :)

Comment: cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/zqWcc1jTq

Comment: Are you sure that `long int` is bigger than `int` on your machine? Does it also happen with `long long int`?

Comment: `long int` is only guaranteed to have a width of not less than 32 bits: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types.  This is why the fixed width types exist: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, I assumed it would be bigger. Had no idea that the sizes can vary with different machines. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. 
Changing the data type of c to long long int did make the program work.

Comment: @cmannett85 I did not know that, guess I should have researched a little more on this. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Can't reproduce with the code as shown.  But I wouldn't expect to be able to.  Neither a `long` nor an `int` are not guaranteed to be able to represent 10000*10000.  A `long long` can.   Forcing at least one operand of each multiplication to be `long long` would therefore work.    If you're only multiplying by `1L` (as distinct from `1LL`) then overflow is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)

Comment: If your on a Windows platform then a `long` is the same size as an `int` - both are 32 bits. Even when compiling x64. (Note however that they are distinct types.)

Comment: ([Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h))

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on an erroneous premise.

Comment: The title mentions a "type cast", but there are no casts in this code. The question is not about a type cast, but about a type **conversion**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Type of `1LL` is `long long int`. Its size is at least 8 bytes. Type of `c` is `long int`. Its size is at least 4 bytes. Thus you may still have overflow. To avoid this you may use `auto`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
  std::uint32_t a = 100'000;
  std::uint32_t b = 100'000;

  auto r1 = a * b;
  auto r2 = static_cast<std::uint64_t>(a) * b;

  std::cout << "r1 = " << r1 << '\n' 
    << "r2 = " << r2 << '\n';
}
```

[<kbd>Try Online</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MsqodqPEn)

Comment: There is no need to use `auto`. Just declare `c` as `uint64_t` (or `long long`).

Comment: @TonyK `auto` makes that process, well, automated :)

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be environment problem - works fine for me.

```
cat long_int_ex.cpp; g++ -O2 long_int_ex.cpp ; a.out; g++ --version
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a = 100000;
    int b = 100000;
    cout << a * b << endl; 
    long int c = a * 1LL * b;
    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
} 
1410065408
10000000000
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```